# How to render custom video data in Qt ?

Tags: qt, render, qimage

I have never done a Qt video application - newbie in this area. I have a custom video file format to render using Qt. The video file format is 256-byte header, then pixel data, then 256-byte header, then pixel data and so on.
The header consist info like width, height in pixels, bytes per pixels, frame rate etc and the pixel data is in Bayer (GBRG). I may have to process data before display - like convert to RGB (not sure yet). I see there are lot of video related classes like QGL*, QMovie, QVideo* ... don't know where to start ? I have seen mandelbrotwidget example which looks like a good place to start but still need some advice. Also, do I have to write a Qt Image plugin for Bayer pattern?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good advice is to do all by yourself. If you have simple data structure read it by simple `C++`-code.

Conversation from `Bayer RGB` to `RGB` [like here](http://www.siliconimaging.com/RGB%20Bayer.htm) you can also make without using any Qt objects.

And now, when you'll got trivial RGB-image (even in your own structure) per frame, you can show it on widgets such as `QGL*` -- if you prefer `OpenGL` rendering, or Qt's classes such as `QPainter`, `QImage`...

Some more links: [C++ GUI Programming with Qt4, 2nd Edition](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1174421), [Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best place to *start* is by learning the basics of custom drawing in Qt. In short, a very simple implementation would require you to:

1. Create a custom `QWidget` subclass
2. Override the `paintEvent()` method
3. Use a `QPainter`/`QImage` to decode your raw video data into image data and draw it on screen

Qt has lots of good sample code to get you started, such as:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-painting.html

Once you have a simple implementation up and running, and a basic grasp of Qt concepts/classes, *then* you'll be ready to profile, optimize, and make use of more advanced Qt functionality (GL, video) as needed.