# How to display decoded YUV420P format frames into Qt in an efficient way but without OpenGL?

Tags: qt, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to render video decoded from ffmpeg ito Qt in several ways. I tried using QAbstractVideoBuffer here: [How to map a decoded buffer from ffmpeg into QVideoFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641515/how-to-map-a-decoded-buffer-from-ffmpeg-into-qvideoframe) but ALL code examples I find construct a `QImage`  and paint it on the screen, which I think it's **very inneficient**.

I've found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12925009/10116440 that OpenGL can also be used in Qt, but I think it is a bit of an overkill because OpenGL is for rendering intense graphics.

I'm sure there must be a way but I couldn't find anywhere.

So: **how to display decoded YUV420P format frames into Qt in an efficient way but without OpenGL?**

I just need a guide, as https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html#working-with-low-level-video-frames won't help me at all!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using OpenGL. What do you understand by "intense graphics". Sometimes all you want it to draw a full viewport rect to execute some fragment/pixel shader code on (like color space conversion) and then it's one of the GPU APIs to go for. If you want to GPU accelerate and be cross plattform, then it's mostly down to OpenGL… and Vulkan if you are okay with not supporting older GPUs.

Comment: @datenwolf but the decoding is made on ffmpeg, so qt is only going to draw the frames. So shouldn't I do everything on qt? It's just a matter of drawing pixels, so there should be a way

Comment: _So shouldn't I do everything on qt?_ Qt may use itself OpenGL "under the hood". [2D Graphics with QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-graphics.html). Sometimes I'm in doubt whether using Qt/QPainter (although more convenient) can gain same performance like doing this in OpenGL directly. E.g. drawing hundreds of little coordinate systems in OpenGL was faster when done with one shader/VAO than with the lots of red, green, and blue lines in `QPainter` (as I recently had to find out).

Comment: @Scheff: Yes, reducing drawing calls can get you a long way. Especially with all the overhead that comes in abstractions like QPainter, which don't know what you want, and have to provision for any conceivable case.

Comment: Have you actually tried an implementation using `QImage`?  It's probably worth giving it a shot -- you might be pleasantly surprised.  Drawing an image is pretty quick and you can draw on the same `QImage` for subsequent frames (generally speaking).

Comment: QOpenGlWidget or something like that is NOT an overkill. Once you try rendering FullHD/25+fps, you'll see it for yourself. Actually, all QPainter optimizations are about "getting a bit lower". Since DirectX or VDPAU redering are not portable and sometimes require more trouble implementing them, you should definitely try redering your frames into a texture. Worked for me))